# Can I specify where I want the database with Code First Data Migrations?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'd like to use Entity Framework's Code First Data Migrations and I want the database to reside in the App_Data folder.  If I use just code first without a connection string the database is being put in the computer users folder.  I'd like to keep the database with the Visual Studio project for the time being.  I thought the connection string below might work but it does not.

```
<add name="BOEContext"
 connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\BOEContext.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
 providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do you, put it in the OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder builder) of the context

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", "the PATH to the mdf");
```

Or you can just do something like this

```
 <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=D:\TQL.mdf;Initial Catalog=XXX;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

The issue I always had with this is that where the migration runs from determines where the mdf file ends up so if I ran the migration from VS command window against the repo project it would end up in that projects root but if I ran it by using auto migrations when starting a web project using that repo it would end up in the web projects app_data folder which then screwed up running it from the VS command line.

Command line override should be something like

```
Update-Database -Verbose -ConnectionString "CONNECTIONSTRING" -ConnectionProviderName "System.Data.SqlClient"
```

Comment: Is there a way to specify the database location when running migrations from the VS command line ?  i.e. c:\databases\mydatabase.mdf

Comment: Updated answer with the command to override the config file settings.